# CMS Image preview not working an internal demo site

Tags: cms, debug, wysiwyg, image-preview

I have a local demo website which is protected by a `.htaccess` to showcase to the customer. Anyways, in this installation the image preview in the CMS WYSIWYG editor is not working.

In the `system.log` there is an entry:

```
ERR (3): Warning: getimagesize(http://example.com/skin/adminhtml/default/
  test/images/wysiwyg/skin_image.png): 
  failed to open stream: 
  HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
  in /var/www/public/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 71
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento makes HTTP access to fetch the included images from the webserver - even if it might be the same server.

The solution is to allow the local host to access itself without password. In Apache this would be:

```
Require valid-user
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Satisfy Any
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_WysiwygController` controller and replace the code below in the `directiveAction` method:

```
$url = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter')->filter($directive);
```

with:

```
$url = str_replace(Mage::getBaseUrl('media'), Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS, $url);
```